# Arrange features in a table that minimizes covariance

Tags: machine-learning, covariance, combinatorics

I have a dataset of vectors represented by a $n_{rows} \times n_{cols}$ matrix $M$. Each row is a vector and each column is a feature. There are $n_{cols} = n \times n$ features.

We use the sample covariance between features: $$covar(i,j) = \frac{1}{n_{rows}-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n_{rows}} (M_{k,i} - \overset{-}M_{.,i})(M_{k,j} - \overset{-}M_{.,j})$$

How can I sort the indices of the features in an $n \times n$ table $A$, such that their covariances with the indices in their neighbouring cells (up, down, left, right) is minimized ?

In other words, I am trying to minimize a quantity like $$\sum_{i,j} |covar(A_{i,j}, A_{i+1,j})| + |covar(A_{i,j}, A_{i-1,j})| + |covar(A_{i,j}, A_{i,j+1})| + |covar(A_{i,j}, A_{i,j-1})|$$ with the convention that $covar(A_{i,j}, A_{\alpha,\beta}) = 0$ if $\alpha$ or $\beta$ are out of bounds of $A$'s indices.

An algorithm or a close but non-optimal solution would be fine.

Comment: Please tell us the sense in which you mean "covariance."  As an example, a random permutation of the rows will exhibit each row as the realization of a random variable in which, by design, the covariances of these rows *qua* random vectors is zero.  If you mean some empirical measure of covariance, then exactly what is it?  Your use of "up, down, left, right" is particularly puzzling: could you edit this question to explain further?

Comment: Very good, thank you.  Do you really mean to minimize that sum or to minimize a sum of *absolute values* of the covariances?  (Some statement of the underlying problem you're trying to solve would be helpful.)

Comment: Yes you are right. I added the absolute values. I'm trying to get a smooth (if  possible) image representation of samples of a dataset.

Comment: It's clear you're working with images.  It isn't at all evident, though, that solving the problem you have stated is a reasonable or effective way to smooth a set of images.  Consider telling us your actual problem rather than presenting this abstracted question, which might or might not help you solve your problem.

Comment: No I'm not working on images. I'm trying to represent my vectors as an image.

Comment: It seems to me that is a *de facto* image, for otherwise what sense would it make to arrange your vectors in this way?  An "image" is not necessarily an array of data collected by a radiation sensor; it consists of any rectangular array of values falling within a given range, where those values might be related to those of nearby cells in the array.  This all suggests that if you could explain what kinds of data your vectors represent, you would increase your chances of getting useful advice and comments.